# Rspec is not working properly with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, mongomapper

I have the following user class

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document 
  key :email, String, :unique => true
end
```

and my rspec code

```
before do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

 describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email
      user_with_same_email.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

raises the following error

```
1) User when email address is already taken 
      Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('5236bec5ebe8660fcb00001a'), accepted_tender_ids: [], avatar: #<Avatar _id: BSON::ObjectId('5236bec3ebe8660fcb000001'), digest: "c7358a60a79905a7d4e3383ba905f1baaab278b06a6f751971344cb91763068f", image: "c7358a60a79905a7d4e3383ba905f1baaab278b06a6f751971344cb91763068f">, busy: false, completed_count: 0, completed_tender_ids: [], confirmed: true, dialogs: [], dislikes: 0, email: "maurice_langworth@treutel.com", role: "customer", subspecializations: [], type: "personal"> not to be valid
```

Expected user is not valid but it is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_with_same_email` will fail to save, so there will not be a second user in the database with your email; assuming that `subject` is `@user`, there will be no conflict and the user will be valid.

Did you forget to define `subject` as `user_with_same_email`?

Comment: No, why do i need subject as user_with_same_email? My code is similar to M.Hartl's code [sample_app_rails_4](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb/#L78)

Comment: Because that's what `it` refers to when you don't specifically specify a subject.